# $routeParams not populating

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Some I'm new to routing and single page web apps, but I've been trying to learn Angular correctly. There's some trouble I'm experiencing with it however and a few weird questions. I followed a guide on structuring your directory and mine looks something like this:

```
app/
    components/
        profile/
            profile.html
            ProfileModel.js
            ProfileController.js
            ProfileFactory.js
    app.module.js
    app.routes.js
```

My main module is located in `app.module.js` and is dependency injected with `ngRoute` and `profile.app` (the module for profile view from `ProfileModel.js`). It is declared like this:

```
angular
    .module('app', ['ngRoute', 'profile.app'])
    .controller('MainController', MainController);

function MainController() {
    this.message = 'This is the home page';
}
```

Then in my `app.routes.js` file, I have declared all the routes the applications needs (so far only one, which is profile):

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .config(routeConfig);

routeConfig.$inject = ['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider'];

function routeConfig ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/user/:user_id', {
                templateUrl: '/app/components/profile/profile.html',
                controller: 'ProfileController',
                controllerAs: 'profile'
            }
        )
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });
}
```

This is my `ProfileController.js`:

```
angular
    .module('app.profile')
    .controller('ProfileController', ProfileController);

ProfileController.$inject = ['ProfileFactory', '$routeParams'];

function ProfileController(ProfileFactory, $routeParams) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.user_id = $routeParams.user;

    console.log($routeParams.user_id);
    vm = ProfileFactory.userProfile(vm.user_id); //Gets the profile of the user and sets to to vm


}
```

So I have two main questions. `$routeParams.user_id` is logged as nothing despite I have defined the route in `app.routes.js`. This is weird because I have an `ng-view` directive in my `index.html` (the HTML file that includes every single `.js` file). Which means that I should have immediate access to the routing parameters once the controller and its dependencies are instantiated. However, when I go to http://example.com/user/1, I get nothing logged (undefined).

My second question is I included `ngRoute` as a dependency in `profile.app` and my main module (in which `profile.app` is a dependency). However, I later removed `ngRoute` from `profile.app` as a dependency, yet I left the injection of `$routeParams` inside my `ProfileController` and AngularJS didn't complain at all. This seems weird because the dependency is no longer explicitly present inside `profile.app`. So how come I can still seemingly inject `$routeParams` despite not having `ngRoute` in my `profile.app` module? Is it because it is getting `ngRoute` from the main module?

Comment: Check if you have made syntax error in this line vm.user_id = $routeParams.user; Should it not be vm.user_id = $routeParams.user_id as defned in your routes ?

Comment: But why should that matter? The `console.log($routeParams.user_id)` logs undefined

Comment: In that case it doesn't matter. I just thought vm.user_id was undefined because you assigned to it undefined variable. Try using my answer below and see what happens.

Comment: Did you try writing controllerAs: 'vm' in the routes configuration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are setting `controllerAs to 'profile'` but then in the controller you write `var vm = this;`

These two need to be the same so you could write `controllerAs: 'vm'`, or `var profile = this;`

Comment: Yes just tried, thanks for the advice! Unfortunately it didn't change the result

Comment: This definitely is part of the problem. I tried this on my current angular app that I'm working on. I changed controllerAs to something different other than vm which I used in the controller (var vm = this), and it broke the code. In other words I had controllerAs: 'asdf' and var vm = this; And everything was undefined in my controller. When I changed back controllerAs: 'vm' everything went back to normal.

Comment: Try to console.log($scope) and you will see that there is object named profile, but in the view you are trying to access vm which is not present in the $scope object at all.

Comment: Actually I think you're right. I kept changing stuff with `controllerAs` and it ended up working (I think I had some small syntax error that was preventing me from seeing the changes), so thank you for your help!